# get unique values in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am maintaining a block of code, but with very little knowledge of `pug` files. What would be the best to get only the unique values in the dropdown?

some_file.pug

```
div(class="col s6 input-field")
  select(name="car_id")
    each val, index in dropDownCars
      if (dropDownCars.length > 0 && selectedCar && val.car_id == selectedCar)
        option(value=val.car_id selected="selected") #{val.car_name}
      else
        option(value=val.car_id) #{val.car_name}
  label Cars
    div(class="col s4")
```

At the moment, I am getting duplicated car names in my dropdown menu. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest to filter distinct cars from `dropDownCars` before it is passed to this template

Answer (score 0):

As @sawim points out, it would be best to try to filter out duplicates in the array before passing it to the Pug template. However, if that's not possible, you can do something like this:

```
select(name='car_id')
  - let uniqueNames = []
  each car in dropDownCars
    if (-1 === uniqueNames.indexOf(car.car_name))
      - uniqueNames.push(car.car_name)
      option(value= car.car_id, selected= (car.car_id === selectedCar)) #{car.car_name}
```

This iterates over the cars, and only renders an `option` element if the car name hasn't been seen before. It also simplifies the logic for adding the `selected` attribute to the appropriate `option`, if there is a selected car.